# Getting referenced object's ID without fetching it

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Suppose I have a MongoEngine document class named Post:

```
class Post(Document):
    author = ReferenceField(Author)
```

How can I get the author's ID of a post without fetching the actual author object?

If I write

```
print post.author.id
```

MongoEngine makes a query to the database to fetch the author object. I can write

```
print post._data["author"]
```

which returns either an Author object, if the `author` field is already dereferenced, or a DBRef object, otherwise.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
post.to_mongo()['author'].id
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. Thank you. However, it does a lot of things in each access besides giving me the id. I would rather encapsulate `self._data["author"].id` in a method in the Post class for efficiency.

Comment: LazyReferenceField could solve this.

Comment: How to get the "id" from LazyReferenceField? because right now it return LazyReferenceField object & not id directly. And I think "lazy_ref_field.id" makes DB req, not sure though.